# trigger to delete a record before insert

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, toad

i have a table with 4 columns

```
1.msisdn
2.accountnumber
3.cardnumber
4.subscriptiondate
```

I want to add a trigger to this table. If the data i am inserting is

```
1.99999999
2.2
3.3298572857239
4.(this can be blank)
```

and the data that is currently in the table is

```
1.99999999
2.1
3.3298572857239
4.(this can be blank)
```

Trigger should check if there is this msisdn `99999999` is already having a record with this cardnumber `3298572857239`. If there is a record already existing in the table, the trigger should delete the existing entry and insert the new one. The final result should look like this

```
1.99999999
2.1
3.3298572857239
4.(this can be blank)
```

I want to keep the value of accountnumber same before and after the trigger. This is what i have tried so far but for this trigger, i am not getting any data in accountnumber column. Please someone help

```
DROP TRIGGER TRIG_TABLEA;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_TABLEA
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLEA 
REFERENCING OLD AS Old NEW AS New 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :new.accountnumber := :old.accountnumber;
 DELETE FROM TABLEA WHERE MSISDN = :new.MSISDN AND CARDNUMBER = :new.CARDNUMBER;
 :new.MSISDN := :new.MSISDN;
 :new.CARDNUMBER := :new.CARDNUMBER;
 :new.accountnumber := :old.accountnumber;
END;
/
```

Comment: Do you need a trigger ar could a MERGE be a solution? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding unique constraints on msisdn and cardnumber but it didn't work(affecting the functionality of app). if its a trigger i thought we can avoid multiple entries of same cardnumber assigned to a single msisdn in table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do a delete-and-insert. You want `MERGE`. The only thing that can change in your statement is accountnumber and subscriptiondate. You don't say where the data is coming from, so I assume this is a PL/SQL procedure with p_* as the parameters. So you want something like this:

```
MERGE INTO mytable trg
USING ( SELECT p_accountnumber, p_subscriptiondate FROM dual ) src
   ON ( trg.msisdn = p_msisdn AND trg.cardnumber )
 WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT ( msisdn, accountnumber, cardnumber, subscriptiondate )
      VALUES ( p_msisdn, p_accountnumber, p_cardnumber, p_subscriptiondate )
 WHEN MATCHED SET ( cardnumber = p_cardnumber, subscriptiondate = p_subscriptiondate)
```

This will do an insert if the row doesn't exist or update an existing row if it does.

Comment: the data is coming from a web service. it checks the TABLEA and does the insert. sorry i am a little beginner in this stuff. and i dont think we get any data for subscriptiondate from the webservice, the insert will be only accountnumber, msisdn and cardnumber.

Comment: So this assumes you're running a PL/SQL statement where p_msisdn, p_cardnumber, p_accountnumber, and p_subscriptiondate are the parameters. If you're not getting subscriptiondate, you can just leave it out.

Comment: please when i do select p_cardnumber from dual, it says invalid identifier.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming this was inside a stored procedure where those are parameters. You don't want to do this merge inside your trigger (look up "mutating table" error). This would replace whatever `insert` you're doing.